# How to create Folder directory in Android API 30 or Android R version device

Tags: android

File file = new File(MATTApplication.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "MATT_LOGS");//new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MATT_LOGS");
if (!file.mkdirs()) {
//file.mkdir();
file.mkdirs();
}
filePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName;

Comment: Please post code in a code block.

Comment: Tell in your post what you want and what does not work. If you have any questions put them in your post.